# Address line from google map location

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm trying to get the address line from longitude and latitude in a text view but it never shows in the text view and the map is blank.
this is my code including the toolbar and navigation bottom and the permission:

```
public class Map extends AppCompatActivity {

SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
FusedLocationProviderClient client;
private Toolbar toolbar;
View view;
TextView textLocation;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_map);

    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
    textLocation = findViewById(R.id.location);

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(Map.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        getLocation();
    }else {
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Map.this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},44);
    }

    view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
    view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.lightGray);
    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    ImageView toolbar_icon = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_icon);
    TextView toolbar_title = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_title);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.map);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.map:
                    return true;
                case R.id.camera:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            ,Camera.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.home:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            ,MainActivity.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    return true;
                case R.id.friends:
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext()
                            ,Friends.class));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
```

get the location from google map and here where   I'm trying to get   the line address in the textView:

```
private void getLocation() {

    Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation() ;
    task.addOnSuccessListener((new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final Location location) {
            if(location != null){
                supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        MarkerOptions op = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("IM HERE");
                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
                        googleMap.addMarker(op);

                        try {
                            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);

                            textLocation.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0 ));


                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                });
            }
        }
    }));
}
```

request for permission:

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 44: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLocation();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

latitude and longitude for my current location are shown right but still, the map is blank and the address line is not shown in the TextView.

Comment: what do you mean by "it never shows"?

Comment: the address line doesn't show in the text view and also the map is blank and the marker is not there

Comment: run it through the debugger. is the data getting returned? if yes, then it's a UI issue. if no, its a data issue